# Detect if specified url is an image in Android?

Tags: android, image, http, url

How to detect quickly if a specified URL contains an image in Android?

I have link of type `http://foo.bar/w23afv` so naive approach like checking end of URL string won't work here.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Check if the HTTP  [`Content-Type`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.17) response header starts with `image/`.

```
URLConnection connection = new URL("http://foo.bar/w23afv").openConnection();
String contentType = connection.getHeaderField("Content-Type");
boolean image = contentType.startsWith("image/");
```