# Validate Specfic URL input in EditText for android

Tags: android, url, save, jsoup

My application is about downloading an image from a specific website e.g. `www.example.com/img-...`

The user will input the url for the img to the EditText field. e.g. `www.example.com/img-123`

My problem is that when the user inputs a wrong URL, i.e. one with no no image, it is empty e.g. `www.example.com/img-222`

I want to detect this and tell the user their input does not link to an image and try again.

I'm using the `isValidUrl()` function to detect if the input is a WEB_URL only but what I want is that when the entered url has no image, the program should tell them it is an incorrect format for url.

I'm using Jsoup.connect(url).get(); to connect to the url and get the image and save it

```
private boolean isValidUrl(String url) {
    Pattern p = Patterns.WEB_URL;
    Matcher m = p.matcher(url);
    if(m.matches())
        return true;
    else
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Let me just understand this a little better. What you want to do is connect to the url in question and check if there is an image there before allowing the user to continue with the url they entered?

Comment: if you have an android device .. check the Instagram downloader App .. I want something similar to the input box EditText . when you enter a URL that has no image or video .. the program will not save anything or do anything and says wrong URL it least ... My App is saving anything from the URL even it's empty .. for example I get my img.jpg with size = 0 bytes for any URl that has no data.... and I don't want that

Comment: Kindly go through following link, if it helps:-

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453641/detect-if-specified-url-is-an-image-in-android][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453641/detect-if-specified-url-is-an-image-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String[] schemes = {"http","https"}; //DEFAULT schemes = "http", "https", "ftp"

UrlValidator urlValidator = new UrlValidator(schemes);

if (urlValidator.isValid("http://www.google.com")) {
    //url is valid
}else{
    //url is invalid
}
```

Use Apache [commons-validator](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/) [URLValidator class](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/UrlValidator.html)

Answer (score 2):

We can use android native **android.webkit.URLUtil** class to validate any kind of url.

```
URLUtil.isValidUrl(downloadImaheEditText.getText().toString());
```

it will **return** true if **valid** else **false**.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it worked for me. Please find the code snippet below:

```
public static boolean isURL(String url) {
        Pattern p = Patterns.WEB_URL;
        Matcher m = p.matcher(url.toLowerCase());
        return m.matches();
    }
```